# How to get Object type parameter in Spring Portlet MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, combobox, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I am working on Spring Portlet MVC. I have a table which name is "CLASS". CLASS table have composite primary keys. I want to use CLASS table in other table. I want to list CLASS table items in a combobox.

When combobox is selected, I must get CLASS's composite id's. But I can't get id. Because id is CLASSID type.(and id is an object) I get just int,string.. type parameters from combobox.

Is it possible to get object from combobox? And if answer yes, how to do this?

Regards.

```
  <form:select path="classId">          
            <form:options items="${classes}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
  </form:select>
```

classId is object. I can get name values and other values from classes array. But I can't get classId value. It returns null. How can I get object type parameter in Spring Portlet MVC?

Comment: Can you show us some code, what have you tried to do?

Comment: So if id1 and id2 are the columns that make up the composite key, what do you want to see in dropdown? Something like id1,id2?

Comment: Not. I want to see name column.

Comment: itemValue="name" does not help?

Comment: It is possible to bind to objects, not just primitive types and Strings. Your combobox is bound to classId. If classId is an object which has id and name fields with appropriate setters, then those should be populated when you submit the form. Please provide some code for your form controller.

Answer (score 0):

check "Type Conversion" to convert you Id to string and vies reverse check it in [spring reference here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)